# What's the difference between Request.Security.Tokens and Request.Security.Elements in WSE 3?

Tags: .net, security, wse

So I'm trying to get a WSE 2.0 SP3 client to work with a WSE 3.0 server. I'm running into an issue with this line of code on the client:

```
transaction.RequestSoapContext.Security.Elements.Add(new MessageSignature(token));
```

I'm wondering how important is this line if the client is already using the following line of code:

```
transaction.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(token);
```

Does anyone know what benefits the first line of code provides over the second?

Comment: Just to be clear: are you aware that WSE is obsolete?

Comment: I am aware, but our vendor is not using .NET 3.0, so I can't use WCF.

Comment: Make sure the vendor is aware. Send them to http://johnwsaundersiii.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!600A2BE4A82EA0A6!860.entry.